# Im trying to get this method for temperatures to print properly but im stuck

Tags: java, methods

```
public static void temperatures (int minTemp, int maxTemp, int increment ){
int F = 0; // Fahrenheit
double C, K; //Celsius, Kelvin

for ( minTemp = 0; minTemp <= maxTemp ; minTemp++){
   C = ( F - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;
      K = C + 273.15;
    increment++;
System.out.println( temperatures );
}
}//end temperatures
```

> //This is what is supposed to print
>
> //Fahrenheit    Celsius    Kelvin
>
> //-----  |  -------  | ------
>
> //    10    |   -12.22  |   260.93

Also it loops 10 times so Fahrenheit goes 10 - 100 etc. and then stops so im thinking the for loop needs to loop 10 times rather how it is but i'm not too sure because i can't print anything

Comment: That doesn't look like it will compile.  You're trying to print your method name rather than any of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class BinarySearchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        temperatures(0, 100, 10);
    }
    public static void temperatures(int minTemp, int maxTemp, int increment) {
        double c, k; // Celsius, Kelvin
        for (int f =minTemp;f <= maxTemp; f+=increment) {
            c = (f - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
            k = c + 273.15;
            System.out.printf("%3d|%8.2f|%8.2f\n",f,c,k);
        }
    }// end temperatures
}
```

**Output:**

```
  0|  -17.78|  255.37
 10|  -12.22|  260.93
 20|   -6.67|  266.48
 30|   -1.11|  272.04
 40|    4.44|  277.59
 50|   10.00|  283.15
 60|   15.56|  288.71
 70|   21.11|  294.26
 80|   26.67|  299.82
 90|   32.22|  305.37
100|   37.78|  310.93
```